# INSERT statement returns a policy violation (USING expression)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, row-level-security

I am using AWS Aurora Postgres 14 (14.5) and have this table set-up (with the help of Diesel in Rust) ->

```
create table contacts (
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    user_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    contact_data JSONB,
    user_groups TEXT[],
    tenant_groups TEXT[],
    tags TEXT[],
    PRIMARY KEY (email, user_id)
);
```

With policies ->

```
ALTER TABLE contacts FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
CREATE POLICY select_contacts_policy ON contacts 
FOR SELECT
USING (user_id = current_setting('myapp.user_id'));
ALTER TABLE contacts ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY insert_contacts_policy ON contacts 
FOR INSERT
WITH CHECK (true);
ALTER TABLE contacts ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

While inserting new data to this table, I first set a session parameter called `user_id` (a string) (using Diesel's [sql_query](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/dsl/fn.sql_query.html) function)->

```
sql_query(format!("SET SESSION myapp.user_id = '{user_id}';")).execute(pg_conn)?;
```

Then I insert using diesel ->

```
diesel::insert_into(contacts::table)
    .values(&contacts) # a custom struct
    .on_conflict((contacts::email, contacts::user_id))
    .do_update()
    .set(&contacts)
    .execute(pg_conn)?;
```

After this query, the `user_id` is reverted to a default ->

```
sql_query("SET SESSION myapp.user_id = -1;").execute(pg_conn)?;
```

The diesel function call translates to this SQL Query (got it from postgres logs) ->

```
INSERT INTO "contacts" ("email", "user_id", "contact_data", "user_groups", "tenant_groups", "tags") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) ON CONFLICT ("email", "user_id") DO UPDATE SET "email" = $7, "user_id" = $8, "contact_data" = $9, "user_groups" = $10, "tenant_groups" = $11, "tags" = $12
```

Upon running this query, I get this error message when there is a conflict and the update branch is triggered  ->

`new row violates row-level security policy (USING expression) for table "contacts"`

I have a somewhat similar (without multiple users but the same schema) postgres installation (v 14.8) on my local which is able to upsert without any issues.

Additional information ->

The user working on this is a different one called `backend` user

The access privileges -> [Snapshot of access privileges for the contacts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgCnV.png)

I tried to run an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query and log it to see where the error occurs but that query results in policy violation before completion. If I run without the `ANALYZE` flag, it just prints the query plan (but I want to know where and what is resulting in that violation)

Comment: Please clarify: do I understand that correctly that you are running the same statement twice, with different settings for `myapp.user_id`? It would be easier if you could reproduce the problem in pure SQL, so that I can try it out easily.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am setting a session before each `INSERT` statement using `SET SESSION`. Once the upsert is done, I am reverting back to the default value for `user_id`. If another user sends a request with their `user_id`, the whole process repeats.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  You could try running the three commands in succession and that would replicate the flow. I am running them as a shell command using `psql` since the backend user doesn't have a database of its own to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`. A plain `INSERT` or an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` would succeed.

You can only update rows that you can see, that is, rows for which you have a `FOR SELECT` policy, as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html) describes:

> [...] queries that require `SELECT` permissions, such as `UPDATE`, will also only see those records that are allowed by the `SELECT` policy.

So it is the `FOR SELECT` policy and the (missing) `FOR UPDATE` policy that give you trouble here. This is somewhat surprising, since one could argue that you should only get that error if there is a conflict during the `INSERT`. However, to determine whether there is a conflict or not, you already need to be able to `SELECT` from the table. Adding a `FOR SELECT` policy would make the statement succeed if there is no conflict. If there *is* a conflict, you need an additional `FOR UPDATE` policy.

You'll have to add policies that allow the inserting role unconditional updates and selects:

```
CREATE POLICY inserter_may_select ON contacts FOR SELECT TO inserter
   USING (TRUE);
CREATE POLICY inserter_may_update ON contacts FOR UPDATE TO inserter
   USING (TRUE);
```

Comment: Adding a `FOR UPDATE` policy worked! For my usecase, I set it up exactly as the `SELECT` policy. I still don't understand why the upsert worked on my local without the update policy but that's something for me to figure out. Thanks @Laurenz Albe!